# XSLT - how to match any non-text node children?

Tags: xslt, match, children

I'm new to XSLT and I can't figure out how to get an xsl:if that matches when there are no child tags.

I want this to match:

```
<context>
    howdy
</context>
```

And this not:

```
<context>
    <child>
        howdy
    </child>
</context>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the relevant xpath expression should look like:

```
//context[not(./*)]
```

Comment: Sweet thanks!  I was trying things with text().  I would have thought * matched text nodes also...

Comment: ./* is the same as just *, so you can leave out the "./" part, as in: //context[not(*)]. Also, "*" is short for "child::*", and the "principal node type" for the child axis is elements. Thus it only selects elements. Similarly, "@*" (which is short for "attribute::*") only selects attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You could also specify  `count(child::*) = 0 .`